# command to edit /tcb/files/auth/s/someuser

Tags: unix, hp, aix

is there a command in HP Unix used to change for example min age for password in this file without actually editing the file?

/tcb/files/auth/s/someuser

it has to do with trusted or non-trusted system...

Answer (score 2):

When using tcb use the following command:

```
/usr/lbin/modprpw -m mintm=5 someuser
```

Alternatively you can use sam (equivalent to smitty)